# Rails - Render JSON string containing HTML code

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, json

I'm trying to get Hotel Information from the Expedia API .

So I have :

```
    api = Expedia::Api.new
    response = api.get_information({:hotelId => params[:id]})

     data_hash = JSON.parse(response.body.to_json)

   @site = ObjetTouristique.new(

           :nom =>   data_hash['HotelInformationResponse']['HotelSummary']['name'],
           :numDepartement =>   data_hash['HotelInformationResponse']['HotelSummary']['postalCode'],
           :urlImageWiki => data_hash['HotelInformationResponse']['HotelImages']['HotelImage'][0]['url'],
           :description => {
               :fr => data_hash['HotelInformationResponse']['HotelDetails']['propertyDescription']
            }

     )
```

My problem is : `data_hash['HotelInformationResponse']['HotelDetails']['propertyDescription']` contains some HTML code :

```
description: {:fr=>"\"&lt;p&gt;&lt;b&gt;Situation de l&apos;établissement&lt;/b&gt; &lt;br /&gt;En choisissant l&apos;établissement Molitor Paris by MGallery, vous séjournerez dans la zone Trocadéro de Paris, à quelques minutes seulement du site Stade Roland Garros et à proximité du site Tour Eiffel. Cet hôtel 5 étoiles se trouve tout près de Parc des Princes et Hippodrome d&apos;Auteil.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;b&gt;Chambres&lt;/b&gt; &lt;br /&gt;Les 124 chambres de l&apos;établissement vous invitent à la détente et comprennent un minibar. L&apos;accès Wi-Fi à Internet gratuit vous permet de rester en contact avec le reste du monde. Les commodités offertes par l&apos;établissement comprennent un téléphone, mais aussi un coffre-fort et un bureau.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;b&gt;Loisirs, Spa, Prestations Premium&lt;/b&gt; &lt;br /&gt;Rejoignez le spa de l&apos;établissement, un centre bien-être qui propose des massages, et permettez qu&apos;on prenne soin de vous. Profitez des nombreuses infrastructures de loisirs offertes par l&apos;établissement et qui comprennent notamment une piscine extérieure, une piscine couverte et un sauna. Cet hôtel propose également l&apos;accès Wi-Fi à Internet gratuit, un service de garde d&apos;enfants et un service d&apos;organisation de mariages.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;b&gt;Restauration&lt;/b&gt; &lt;br /&gt;Pendant votre séjour dans cet hôtel, vous pourrez manger dans un des 2 restaurants ou profiter du service en chambre 24 heures sur 24. L&apos;établissement vous invite à la détente dans un de ses 2 bars/lounges.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;b&gt;Affaires, autres prestations&lt;/b&gt; &lt;br /&gt;Les commodités incluent l&apos;accès gratuit haut débit à Internet (par câble), un centre d&apos;affaires et un service de départ express. Cet hôtel dispose de 3 salles de réunions pouvant accueillir toutes sortes d&apos;événements.&lt;/p&gt;\"
```

I tried MANY things such as `<%= @site.description[:fr].html_safe %>` but I can't display it properly. Using `html_safe` renders correctly the html tags like `<p><br /><b> etc...` but they are not interpreted :

[image: The result with .html_safe]

I spent hours trying to solve it. Now I think I need some help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following to solve:

```
<%== CGI.unescapeHTML(@site.description[:fr]).html_safe %>
```

Comment: It works, thank you very much. Just a little thing, do you know why the double quotes before and after description[:fr] remains ?

Comment: The data has `\"` at the beginning and the ending. You trim them at first by `gsub(/\A"|"\Z/, '')`